Hiding a method in a descendant class in C# is apparently not working when used in a generic method
The following test fails, which I did not expect.
Why does the generic version of the method not return the same as the non generic version.
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace UnitTest1
{
    // we declare some classes that hide a base class method and implement an interface
    public interface IGet
    {
        string Get();
    }

    public class GetA: IGet
    {
        public string Get()
        {
            return "a";
        }
    }

    public class GetB: GetA
    {
        public new string Get()
        {
            return "b";
        }
    }

    public static class GetUtil<T> where T : IGet
    {
        public static string Get(T aGetObject)
        {
            return aGetObject.Get();
        }
    }

    public static class GetAUtil
    {
        public static string Get(GetA aGetObject)
        {
            return aGetObject.Get();
        }
    }

    public static class GetBUtil
    {
        public static string Get(GetB aGetObject)
        {
            return aGetObject.Get();
        }
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class NewUnitTest
    {
        // Check that the generic and non generic versions of the methods to return the same thing
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestGetInterfaceImplemetors()
        {
            var a = new GetA();
            var b = new GetB();
            Assert.AreEqual(GetAUtil.Get(a), GetUtil<GetA>.Get(a));
            Assert.AreEqual(GetBUtil.Get(b), GetUtil<GetB>.Get(b)); //This fails, why?
        }
    }
}

I expected that GetUtil<GetB>.Get(b) be the same as GetBUtil.Get(b) I didn't expect a functionality change between the generic and non generic methods. Could someone please explain why this test fails. Isn't the IGet type restriction in the generic declaration just that, a type restriction? It's acting as if the passed value is considered to be of that type and not the type passed when using the generic class.

// Why does this pass - what do you expect instead?

This is exactly why we avoid using new to shadow a method. It's a horrible kludge.

GetUtil<T> only knows that T : IGet, it knows nothing else about type T, so the compiler will call IGet.Get in all cases. GetBUtil.Get knows that the argument is a GetB, which has a shadow method, so the compiler will call GetB.Get. IMHO shadow methods are a stupid language "feature". Instead you probably want GetA.Get to be virtual, and for GetB to override it.

OfCourse overriding is the correct way to override :) - In Java you can't even reintroduce methods like this. However, this was a test to validate the hiding / shadow functionality. As per your comment "it knows nothing else about type T" I don't agree with that statement because in the failing test that T is of type GetB explicitly and the compiler should know this. My understanding was that T would be replaced with the corresponding types making GetUtil essentially the same as GetBUtil. Unfortunately this does not appear to be the case which in my humble opinion is rather odd.

Makes perfect sense to me. Generic methods are not recompiled from scratch for each type, you can only call the methods that you know are there at compile time, and those are the only methods that will be called. var iget = getB as IGet; iget.Get(); will call GetA.Get() as that is the implementation of IGet. GetB.Get might as well be called .newGet or something, as you can only call it if you know your argument is of type GetB.

And as I said, if you use shadow methods, be prepared to deal with these surprises. The only thing this feature is "useful" for is source compatibility. And that is dubious at best. If you are using new in production code, don't. Because you will be surprised by it's behaviour at some point. Rename the method instead. Visual studio will even help you locate where the method is used and rename them too.

I think the answer to my question is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generics-in-the-run-time
The issue being that the generic method when used with reference types is actually the same method, unlike when it is used with value types. This causes the behaviour  I am seeing.
